# When was the last coal mine in Germany established?

Tags: germany

Recently, the last German coal mine (excluding brown coal) was closed. For more than 50 years, German mines were struggling because their coal was too expensive.

I wonder when and where the last German coal mine was founded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may depend a bit on meanings, whether we are looking for an entirely new colliery or a pit.

But if we define that as measured by investing good money into 'something new' related to mining, like establishing a new structure above ground called pit head or headframe, for actually extracting coal through that structure, then [Neu-Monopol](http://ruhrzechenaus.de/kamen-bergkamen/monopol.html) in Bergkamen seems to be the last such one built:
Start of operations 13. October 1981.

> In Bergkamen ist die wohl letzte neue deutsche Steinkohlenzeche in Betrieb gegangen. Sie sollte den Bergbau auf Jahrzehnte sichern. Doch schon nach zehn Jahren war ihr Schicksal besiegelt. Der damalige nordrhein-westfälische Ministerpräsident Johannes Rau (SPD) war am 13. Oktober 1981 sogar eigens nach Bergkamen gekommen, um die neue Zeche „Neu-Monopol“ in Betrieb zu nehmen. Der hochrangige Besuch, der später Bundespräsident wurde, war sogar nur die Vertretung.
>
> [Michael Dörlemann: "Eine neue Zeche für nur gut zehn Jahre", Hellweger Anzeiger, 5 Dec 2018.](https://www.hellwegeranzeiger.de/Bergkamen/Eine-neue-Zeche-fuer-nur-gut-zehn-Jahre-Plus-1354048.html)

But as you might infer from the first link, the bigger colliery coal-field was was already tapped into in 1879.

The last ever tunnel however was newly dug in 1987 and started operations in 1990, although that one was only used for ventilation.

> [WP: Ruhrgebietsbergbau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruhrbergbau)
> Der letzte im Ruhrbergbau in Betrieb genommene Schacht ist der Schacht 9 der [Zeche Auguste Victoria](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeche_Auguste_Victoria) nördlich der Lippe in Haltern. Er dient seit 1990 der Bewetterung der Abbaufelder unter Haltern und der Hohen Mark. Auch das Bergwerk Auguste Victoria wurde 1991 von der Ruhrkohle AG erworben.

If the goal is the bigger structure collieries [then Wikipedia listed candidates are:](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Bergwerken_in_Nordrhein-Westfalen)

> Soboll    Bochum  Langendreer 1963
> Wilhelm Wahmann, Kleinzeche Bochum  Laer    1967
> Justus  Dortmund    Kley    1956    1967    Kleinzeche
> Prosper-Haniel  Bottrop     1974    2018    in Stilllegung
> Auguste Victoria/Blumenthal Kreis Recklinghausen    Marl    2001    2006
> West    Kreis Wesel Kamp-Lintfort   2001    2012    2001 aus Niederberg  und Friedrich Heinrich; letzte Kohle wurde am 21. Dezember 2012 gefördert

Note that the dates not always represent really newly built structures but sometimes have to be better characterised as organisational restructurings.

The list [Zechen in chronologischer Reihenfolge ihrer Gründung](http://www.ruhrkohlenrevier.de/zechenchro.html) has as last entry:

> [Zeche Vereinigte Pörtingssiepen / Carl Funke, founded 1967](http://www.ruhrkohlenrevier.de/ob1187.html)